# Sharing Platforms - Facebook button_count Generating an Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-like, sharing

I am using below code in my `ASP.NET` `web application` which took from [addthis](http://www.addthis.com) website.

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4eb279bd549b74d7"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

But this cause an `ERROR` saying `The string 'fb:like:layout' contains too many device filters. There can be only one`

I have removed the `fb:like:layout="button_count"` from code and then its working. But it generating wired spaces among the buttons.

If anybody knows whats the wrong with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I think [Rashmi Kant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1010382/rashmi-kant) has the best solution in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994108/sharing-platforms-facebook-button-count-generating-an-error#comment9800397_7994335) - use the echo inline tags.

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" <%="fb:like:layout"%>="standard"></a>
```

This answer is also given on the [AddThis support forums](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/153679-the-string-fb-like-layout-contains-too-many-device-filters-there-can-be-only-one-).

Answer (score 3):

just remove **fb:** from fb:like:layout and **g:** g:plusone:size, it has no effect on code

may help you

http://oops-solution.blogspot.com/

Comment: yes, this way working. but i have problem with the style. buttons have big spaces among them

Comment: <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like"  <%="fb:like:layout"%>="standard" <%="fb:like:width"%>="244"></a>

Comment: That way also screwing the design style

Answer (score 1):

You can also use javascript to change the attributes

```
var e = document.getElementById('like-button');
e.setAttribute('fb:like:layout', 'box_count');
var f = document.getElementById('tw');
f.setAttribute('tw:count', 'vertical');
var g = document.getElementById('plusone');
g.setAttribute('g:plusone:size', 'tall');
```

Answer (score -1):

Used the following code,

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
       <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" <%="fb:like:layout"%>="button_count"></a>
       <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
       <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" <%="g:plusone:size"%>="medium"></a>
       <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
```